# How to create a route for a button doing a post in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am brand new to Rails programming and need some help with creating a route.

I have a view that lists a set of fields in a table, and I have a button that the user can click that should populate the current time.

For example, in my view **/apps/views/patients/index.html.erb**

Last Name      First Name     Action
Smith          Joe            [CheckIn]

In the code for my button I have

```
<%= button_to "CheckIn", :action => "set_checkintime" %>
```

And in my controller, I have the following method

```
def set_checkintime
    self.checkedin = Time.now
end
```

When I load the page, rails throws an error 
No route matches {:action=>"set_checkintime", :controller=>"patients"}

I know that I need to create a route in my routes.rb file, but I don't know how to do so properly.  The desired behavior is that the user clicks on the 'checkin' button and the 'checkedin' field of the database is updated, but I don't move to a new page.

Comment: you should start from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 2):

1st you need to add a route in your routes.rb which I deduce that is a post.

For instance:

```
put "set_checkintime" => "patients#set_checkintime"
```

And your button will be:

```
<%= button_to "CheckIn", :action => "set_checkintime", :method => :put %>
```

Ok, if this works when you click in the button rails will redirect you to the file set_checkintime.html.erb, and you should have it.

To stay in the same page you need to make an ajax call. In rails you can use :remote => true to stay in the same page. In the controller you need to respond_to the js... Just check out this [example](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/ajaxify-your-site-with-remote-true/#.Uw4pNXV_uY4).

Comment: You don't need `method: post` because it's a `button_to` [API Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

Comment: to be precise you should set your method to `:put` if you want to be in accordance with `REST` because you are not creating something but updating something!

Comment: I added the route and changed my button code as you've suggested, and as you stated, it does redirect me to a non-existent page.  I'm not clear, though, on how to use AJAX to stay on the same page.  This is my very first attempt at rails, so I'm very new.

Comment: you need to create a view called /apps/views/patients/set_checkintime.html.erb because rails will render it... The ajax it's more complicated, you should put it working without ajax first...

Comment: I created that page with a title and a header, but when I click my 'checkin' button, I still get an error from rails....No route matches [POST] "/set_checkintime"

Answer (score 1):

In your `routes.rb` add

```
resources :patients do
  member do
    put 'set_checkintime'
  end
end
```